# Figure block with shadow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

photo with result and what need

[image]
Left image is result what i recieved in a browser, right - figma and what needs, i have not any ideas how to do semicircle with shadow under coin and then hover effect like in right image

```css
.currencies_block {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  padding: 9.3rem 2rem 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.currencies_i_w {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.currencies_text_w p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-5 justify-content-center">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="currencies_block">
      <div class="currencies_i_w">
        <img src="../assets/images-coins/bitcoin-2.png" alt="Bank transfers" class="currencies_i" />
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_text_w">
        <p class="currencies_text">Bitcoin (BTC)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="currencies_block">
      <div class="currencies_i_w">
        <img src="../assets/images-coins/ethereum.png" alt="NGN deposits" class="currencies_i" />
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_text_w">
        <p class="currencies_text">Ethereum (ETH)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to use SVGs for the boxes and overlay the crypto image on top. Just use CSS to increase the size slightly on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time, technology has improved. Now it is quite easy to implement the idea. The cutout is done with `mask-image: radial-gradient()`, and the curly shadow with `filter: drop-shadow()`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Russo+One&display=swap');
.card {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  width: 339px; height: 301px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 5px 8px #0004);
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px; left: 50%; z-index: 1;
  width: 170px; height: 170px;
  transform: translatex(-42%) perspective(300px) rotatey(30deg);
  border-radius: 12px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-4px 0 0px #48140a) contrast(150%);
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.card:hover .icon {
  transform: translatex(-36%) perspective(276px) rotatey(34deg) scale(1.24);
}

.band {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  height: 187px; width: 339px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, #fff0 75%, #ffff 75%), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, #ffff 75%, #fff0 75%), linear-gradient(to right bottom, #f15e29, #fff001);
  background-size: 339px 464px, 339px 464px, 100% 100%;
  background-position: left 50% bottom -370px, left 50% bottom -40px, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient( circle at 50% 7px, #fff0 90px, #ffff 91px);
  mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 7px, #fff0 90px, #ffff 91px);
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
.card:hover .band {
  background-position: left 50% bottom -147px, left 50% bottom 93px, 0 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.band::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px; left: 3px;
  width: 333px; height: 181px;
  border-radius: 9px;
  background-color: #ffff;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 17px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 65px; width: 100%;
  font-size: 139%; font-family: 'Russo One', sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f4f5f5;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="icon" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/02/13/51/bitcoin-3125488_960_720.png" alt="">
  <div class="band"></div>
  <div class="name">Bitcoin (BTC)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just suggested an option that needs to be completed

```css
.currencies_block {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 7rem;
  padding: 9.3rem 2rem 2.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 1rem;
 
}
.currencies_block:before{
  content:'';
  background:#ffffff;
  position:absolute;
  width:250px;
  height:125px;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  top:0px;
  right:50%;
  margin-right:-125px;
  box-shadow:       inset 0px 0px 2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}



.currencies_i_w {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.currencies_text_w p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-4 g-5 justify-content-center">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="currencies_block">
      <div class="currencies_i_w">
        <img src="../assets/images-coins/bitcoin-2.png" alt="Bank transfers" class="currencies_i" />
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_text_w">
        <p class="currencies_text">Bitcoin (BTC)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="currencies_block">
      <div class="currencies_i_w">
        <img src="../assets/images-coins/ethereum.png" alt="NGN deposits" class="currencies_i" />
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_text_w">
        <p class="currencies_text">Ethereum (ETH)</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: need semicircle with background transparent,  because under block card general background is linear-gradient, maybe it can decide to polygon or canvas

Comment: play with the shadows